# Is it good to use STL in making new softwares?

Tags: c++, qt, stl, open-source

Hi I am currently working on an open source project and want to use STL in it. But I am confused that is correct to depend on STL only or it will be good to use Qt like libraries. Because I want to make it cross platform supported. Please suggest.

STL: Standard Template Library for C++

Comment: The STL is as cross platform as it gets.

Comment: Are you really talking specifically about that third party library from SGI? Are you aware of the standard library and how most of the stuff the STL introduced also exist in today's C++ standard library?

Comment: [Is it wrong to use the word "codes" in programming world?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/is-it-wrong-to-use-the-word-codes-in-programming-world) Yes it is. The same applies to "softwares".

Answer (score 2):

That is some confusion in this question.

STL is a part of Standard Library of C++; specifically covering containers and algorithms (and iterators, as a glue between the two).

Qt is cross-platform application framework which purpose is, first and foremost, to provide facilities for abstracting you from platform. It also covers some of functionality provided by STL (i.e. it provides its own containers: as I understand, mostly for historical reasons).

You can freely mix'n'match both libraries. AFAIK you can even use STL algorithms on Qt containers (meaning that Qt containers are STL compliant).

So, answering your question, it is of course *good to use* STL for new software: provided it is properly supported by your compiler, and you know how to use it.

Comment: That was a very good answer indeed &  thanks for clarifying the concepts. I think I still need to learn STL  more deeply.